# open street map AND android app

Tags: android, dictionary

I know I can write an android app using open street mobile map api but I also want to support offline mode in my map. Is there a way to download the map of a city or a country and use it locally on android phone?

thanks.

Comment: @user195678: You can definitely download and use OSM data -- I use TravelDroyd, which uses that facility. However, I don't know if anyone here will necessarily have docs/steps on how to do it.

Comment: TravelDroyd, NavDroyd and MapDroyd doesn't use OSM data directly BTW. They use maps in proprietary format, prepared by their vendor from OSM data. Which makes sense--the format is optimized for mobile consumption, includes only the data that the apps will need etc.

Comment: Is it possible to extract just one rectangular that is good for phone screen then? I am searching online to see if I can display osm data on android. For what I am doing, I just need one piece of map and add a object on the map. It could be any map that fills the screen of a phone.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194233/open-street-maps-api-for-android for some pointers to other solutions (e.g. Android SDKs that offer rendering & offline capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Open Street Maps Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) page for Android? There seems to be a number of open source libraries some of which may have offline caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following combination (it worked very well for me):

- OsmAndMapCreator: for downloading map for offline usage [OsmAndMapCreator](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/downloads/detail?name=OsmAndMapCreator-0.5.1alpha-b5.zip&can=2&q=label%3aFeatured)
- Osmand : andrdoid application for map navigation and tracking [Osmand google project](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/)

Once you install the osmand application on your android you can set the directory on which you will save the offline maps (beside osm, you can use various other sources as google map for example and easily switch between them).

The application have already a very complete set of features, and having the code you can extend/learn from it.