# open street maps api for android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Does anyone know where I can find the open street maps api for android?
I have searched the site and all I can see is other peoples implementations of it.

I'm looking for one which can be integrated into another app and fully customized.

Answer (score 34):

You can integrate OSM by using the Osmdroid API. This gives you functionality very similar to Google maps but you can also use OSM tiles offline if you prepare the tiles with Mobile Atlas Creator (MOBAC)

See [Osmdroid home page (GitHub)](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid)

You just need the osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar in your build path. You don't need an API key like Google demands and tiles get cached, so next time you visit that location you save on data download costs/time.

It's got a few tiny bugs, but overall it's pretty good

Comment: I have to say few is an understatement :) but it all depends on what your trying to do with it.

Comment: Is there SDK available for `iOS`? Can you please share alternative `iOS SDK` if exist?

Answer (score 10):

If you are going for a commercial app them it's worth taking a look at "commercial grade Android SDKs" - all vendors allow you to customise your app (depending on the vendor, the degree of customisation may vary), and I believe all vendors have "free tiers" (payment plans where you actually don't have to pay :) ) that might be good enough for your app (or at least you don't have to pay until your app is commercially successful).

To name a couple Android SDK providers:

- [skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com/) (now Telenav) has an SDK which is able to render maps & display turn by turn navigation on your Android phone. It also supports offline mode. Check out their [developer platform](http://developer.skobbler.com) for details
- [OsmSharp](http://www.osmsharp.com/) also does map rendering and turn by turn navigation. You can pull their code from [github](https://github.com/xivk/OsmSharp)
- [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com/) has a nice [map & routing engine](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api) for Android. I think you could also use their routing service with Mapbox maps (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300866/routing-between-points-with-mapbox) as a starting point). I don't think they can do offline mode