# Access google map without connection in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I'm developing an android application which contains info of certain places. So when the user select one place(an item of a listview) an android map is shown (I'm using android api v2 of google maps), but of course this happens when the user has internet access.
Does anyone know a way of showing a map without connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your application has write external storage permission, maps API v2 keeps a cache, so the map is normally displayed for area shown recently.

If you want to have a full offline map, you would have to embeed your own tiles, which possibly brings your app size to hundreds of MB or you can try to use open street map. See here: [open street maps api for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194233/open-street-maps-api-for-android).