# using openstreetMap in android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am developing an android based application, my application should display nearby locations,

I already used google API to achieve that, but I am facing a problem; which is in my country not all places listed in Google maps, I made my research to solve this problem, I was told to use openstreetmap in order to add places to the map.

could you tell me if it is possible to use openstreetmap and the steps (in general) to do that.

Comment: Have a look at osmdroid. Google for the website.

Comment: @NickT is it possible to use both Google maps and osmdroid??
I just want to add some additional places in my country which are not displayed in Google maps

Comment: Not in the same view. In separate activities it's possible.

Comment: @NickT so all I have to do is add the places I want using osmdroid and make a specific activity to my country.
and rest of the world I use Google maps

Comment: Find the website and have a look for yourself to see if it's appropriate for you. I'm not at my computer at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Project:

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

There is a HowTo in the Wiki section.

from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8194233/1515052):

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer in this question [open street maps api for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194233/open-street-maps-api-for-android/)

The three most popular library for using OSM in android are osmdroid, graphhopper, and mapsforge.