# How to include open street map in android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am new in android, I know how to include google maps in android but I have to work on OSM, can anyone guide me for OSM in android. Thanks

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid , http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/06/example-of-implementing-openstreetmap.html Questions like this asking for source code are not encouraged by SO..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194233/open-street-maps-api-for-android?rq=1